# Disable battery display on lid opening

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I disabled the automatic power-on when the lid is opened. Is there any way to disable the annoying battery display, which appears after opening the lid?

Comment: It serves a useful purpose. Like you, I turned off the ‘boot on lid open’ but I like to know if it needs to be connected to power if the battery is low, or even if it can be started up at all because the battery is almost completely discharged.  That being said, I don’t think this is something under user control to disable.

Comment: if you would disclose the hardware and software it might help

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I hoped at least it would be possible to reduce the time it is being shown. I miss the days when Apple was simple and useful. They had a small band of LEDs on the side showing the battery status.